# XSL comparison of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I am new to xml and would like to compare some values using an xsl stylesheet

```
`<a>
 <b>   <name>foo</name>   </b>
 <b>   <name>bar</name>   </b>
 <b>   <name>fred</name>  </b>
 <b>   <name>fred</name>  </b>
 </a>`
```

I would like to write a style sheet that checks all the b nodes and returns the values that have the same value so using the simple example above i would like the output to resemble :
"Your duplicate strings are fred"

I have used a for each loop to return all the values but comparing the names and returning the duplicates has eluded me.If possible i would like to achieve the comparison by the use of a while type loop.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<xsl:key>`-based solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="kName" match="b/name" use="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//b/name">
      <xsl:if test="count(key('kName', text())) &gt; 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Your duplicate is: ', text(), '&#xA;')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For large input documents this will be more efficient than a solution that uses a `preceding::` check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight and help this solution worked for me very well.

Comment: @tomalak: This certainly can be done a little bit more efficiently, not using `count()` and without any `xsl:for-each` .

Comment: @Dimitre That's why I gave my +1 to your answer. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: The XSLT 2.0 solution and the XPath 2.0 one-liner could also be interesting to you :)

Answer (score 2):

**XSLT 1.0: A simple, solution using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kNameByVal" match="name" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  Your duplicate strings are: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "b/name[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kNameByVal', .)[2])]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:if test="position() >1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:variable name="vSeq" select="data(/a/b/name)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  Your duplicate strings are: <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$vSeq[index-of($vSeq,.)[2]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**III. XPath 2.0 one-liner**

```
$vSeq[index-of($vSeq,.)[2]]
```

This producws all values in a given sequence, that have duplicates (one from a group of duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Using a while loop is against XSLT philosophy, even though it can be done.

There are some much easier way to do what you want, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method='text' />
<xsl:template match="b">
   <xsl:if test='preceding::b/name/text()=./name/text()'>
Your duplicate is: <xsl:copy-of select='./name/text()' />
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is looking for node b, and checking if a preceding b node has the same name text

Comment: +1 pragmatic solution. On a general note, you should avoid "naked" text nodes in your XSL. Rather use `<xsl:text>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight and help this solution worked for me very well.