# XSL - Remove parent Nodes containing certain criteria

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML I am wanting to transform it with xslt. 
The input looks like this.

```
<xmeml>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        <Unit3>tuvw</Unit3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>bcd</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test>
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>cde</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>def</Unit>
        <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        <Unit3>uvwx</Unit3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>efg</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
</xmeml>
```

the output should look like this.

```
<xmeml>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>bcd</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test>
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>cde</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>def</Unit>
        <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>efg</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
        <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
</xmeml>
```

I am wanting to remove any Test nodes that match the following criteria. 
- The Unit3 child node starts-with tuv or uvw.  
- AND Where both the Unit AND Unit2 vales are both found repeated/duplicated in another Test node

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: user1540142, I updated my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi, you seem newish here, so I thought I'd explain why this is being down-voted: It's a good idea to show us that you have had a go at it before asking us for help. For instance: what have you tried yourself? Where has it been a problem for you? If you can add this to your question, we will not only be able to pinpoint your errors better, we'll feel better about helping you :)

Comment: Thanks Taryn, will do in future. This is a tremendous resource of info and people. I'm quickly learning the lingo and correct protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this tweak of Dimitre's solution ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kTest" match="Test" use="concat(Unit, '+', Unit2)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Test[key('kTest', concat(Unit, '+', Unit2))[2]]
   [starts-with(Unit3, 'tuv') or starts-with(Unit3, 'uvw')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As I understand it, the rules of transformation are:

1. Copy all nodes as is, except as indicated following.
2. Exclude all Test nodes have that the following properties:

2.1 There exists another Test node (call it Test(other)) in the document such that:

```
  (Test(reference) / Unit = Test(other) / Unit)   AND
  (Test(reference) / Unit2 = Test(other) / Unit2)
```

2.2  The Unit3 child of the reference Test node starts with tuv or uvw

The output for this is exactly as the OP posted. Interestly, if I have understood the problem correctly, Dimitre has just recently provided a solution to almost the same problem as yours here [XSL comparison of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595102) . Again, if I have understood your problem correctly, the title is misleading. "Removing duplicates" is generally taken to mean de-duping, as in (1,2,2,3) --> (1,2,3) ; whereas what you want, like (1,2,2,3) --> (1,3) is generally described as "selecting unique nodes/values".

Comment: Yes its a tricky one to describe. Basically I want to remove all Test nodes where Unit 3 value starts with tuv or uvw. As a check though I need to also see if there are any duplicate entries as defined by both Unit and Unit2 values. so i think the real question is if Unit3 starts with tuv or uvw and both its Unit and Unit2 values are duplicated in another Test node then delete it. Does that make sense.

Comment: It appears yours is working perfectly. Thank you kind Aussie ;) Thank you too Dimite for being Patient.

Comment: @user1540142: The question is still not edited and quite confusing. I am repeating that you must edit the question and make it clear and unambiguous. For your future questions take special care to ask clear and unambiguous questions so not to waste readers' and your own time. Whenever someone ask ambiguous and unclear question, they are only describing the problem they have asking questions -- not the problem they think they have.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation** (Muenchian grouping - based):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kTest"
   match="Test[starts-with(Unit3, 'tuv') or starts-with(Unit3, 'uvw')]"
          use="concat(Unit, '+', Unit2)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Test[starts-with(Unit3, 'tuv') or starts-with(Unit3, 'uvw')]
    [not(generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kTest', concat(Unit, '+', Unit2))[last()]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xmeml>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
            <Unit3>tuvw</Unit3>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>bcd</Unit>
            <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
            <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
            <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>cde</Unit>
            <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
            <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
            <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>def</Unit>
            <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
            <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
            <Unit3>uvwx</Unit3>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>efg</Unit>
            <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
            <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
</xmeml>
```

**produces the correct result** (implementing all requirements):

```
<xmeml>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>bcd</Unit>
         <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>abc</Unit>
         <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Unit>cde</Unit>
         <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>abc</Unit>
         <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Unit>def</Unit>
         <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>abc</Unit>
         <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
         <Unit3>uvwx</Unit3>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Unit>efg</Unit>
         <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
</xmeml>
```

**Update**:

The OP has his own interpretation of the problem, which is ambiguous and not precisely defined.

With considerable guessing, here is what he may want... :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kTest"
   match="Test" use="concat(Unit, '+', Unit2)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Test[starts-with(Unit3, 'tuv') or starts-with(Unit3, 'uvw')]
    [not(generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kTest', concat(Unit, '+', Unit2))
                                     [not(position()=1)])
                )]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), now the result is identical with what the OP believes is the wanted result**:

```
<xmeml>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>bcd</Unit>
         <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>abc</Unit>
         <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Unit>cde</Unit>
         <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>abc</Unit>
         <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Unit>def</Unit>
         <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>efg</Unit>
         <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
         <Unit3>wxyz</Unit3>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
</xmeml>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre, :) Works a treat!

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Actually it looks like its not picking up the latter match candidate, 2nd Test node from the bottom. Matching Unit and Unit2 values and Unit3 starts with uvw.

Comment: @user1540142: I don't understand what you are saying. Could you, please, explain? The transformation strictly implements all requirements.

Comment: Dimitre the question asks that any Test node with the following requirements should be removed.  if the Unit value matches AND if the Unit2 value matches AND if the Unit3 value starts with uvw OR tuv. The second last Test node in the original contains all three requirements ... but it still remains.

Comment: @user1540142: No, the second last `Test` node doesn't match any other `Test` element according to the requirements. Which other `Test` element do you think it matches?

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Yes it does, Unit = abc , Unit2 = 1234 (which match the first and fifth Test Node) AND Unit3 starts-with uvw.

Comment: @user1540142: In the output the 1st node is deleted (due to this match). The last but one `Test` node *doesn't* match the 5th node, because the 5th node's `Unit3` doesn't start with any of the strings `tuv` or `uvw`. Seems you *again* cannot explain well the problem...

Comment: The 7th nodes Unit 3 does does start with uvw though. Im confused. The 7th is the second last of 8 Test nodes in the example.

Comment: @user1540142: In order a node to be eliminated, its `Unit` and `Unit2` children must have the same values as the `Unit` and `Unit2` children of another `Test` element *and* both these two `Test` elements must have `Unit3` children that start with either `"tuv"` or `"uvw"`, and this `Test` element must not be the last `Test` element in the group. However, the 5th node's `Unit3` child *doesn't* start with any of the strings `"tuv"` or `"uvw"` -- therefore we don't have a match. Even if there were a match, then the 5th node (not the 7th) should have been eliminated, as the 7th would be the last.

Comment: @user1540142: So, please, understand better your question, then *edit* it and provide a new, unambiguous problem definition. I am going to bed now.