# Reporting duplicate or non-duplicate nodes using XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT 1.0 I need to find if there are duplicate nodes or are there single nodes from the `to` and `from` categories.

I have found this [XSL comparison of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595102/xsl-comparison-of-nodes) that is very similar, but couldn't get it to work either.

**XML:**

```
    <acl>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <from>
        <rule>
          <name>1.1.1.1</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.1</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
        <rule>
          <name>1.1.1.3</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.3</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>false</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
        <rule>
          <name>1.1.1.4</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.4</pattern>
          <deny/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
        <fallthrough>
          <allow/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </fallthrough>
      </from>
      <to>
        <rule>
          <name>1.1.1.2</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.2</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
        <rule>
          <name>1.1.1.3</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.3</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>false</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
        <rule>
          <name>1.1.1.4</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.4</pattern>
          <deny/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
        <fallthrough>
          <allow/>
          <log>false</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </fallthrough>
      </to>
    </acl>
```

**Desired Result:**

1.1.1.1 would display "from" (it came from the `from` section)

1.1.1.3 would display "both" (it exists from both the `from` and `to` section)

1.1.1.2 would display "to" (it came from the `to` section)

I have already figured out how to write the 1.1.1.4 as "none" since as long as it shows `<deny/>`, I can print it as "none". But I have no idea how to test if they exist in both sections of the XPath or just one section.

What I have started on but non working.

**XSL: (non working)**

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="acl">
        <xsl:if test="from/rule/name = to/rule/name">
            <xsl:text>both</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

I realize that there are other posts out there that will find copy xml and match it and remove if two nodes are exactly the same. But I'm not trying to remove it, rather trying to report if there are duplicate nodes and where they came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="from" match="from/rule" use="name" />
<xsl:key name="to" match="to/rule" use="name" />

<xsl:template match="/acl">
<result>
    <group desc="from">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="from/rule[not(key('to', name))]"/>
    </group>
    <group desc="to">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="to/rule[not(key('from', name))]"/>
    </group>
    <group desc="both">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="from/rule[key('to', name)]"/>
    </group>
</result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
<group desc="from">
<rule>
          <name>1.1.1.1</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.1</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
</group>
<group desc="to">
<rule>
          <name>1.1.1.2</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.2</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
</group>
<group desc="both">
<rule>
          <name>1.1.1.3</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.3</pattern>
          <allow/>
          <log>false</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
<rule>
          <name>1.1.1.4</name>
          <pattern>1.1.1.4</pattern>
          <deny/>
          <log>true</log>
          <alarm>0</alarm>
        </rule>
</group>
</result>
```

---

**EDIT**

Essentially the same thing, with HTML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="from" match="from/rule" use="name" />
<xsl:key name="to" match="to/rule" use="name" />

<xsl:template match="/acl">
    <h3>From</h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="from/rule[not(key('to', name))]"/>
    <h3>To</h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="to/rule[not(key('from', name))]"/>
    <h3>Both</h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="from/rule[key('to', name)]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="name" /></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<h3>From</h3>
<p>1.1.1.1</p>
<h3>To</h3>
<p>1.1.1.2</p>
<h3>Both</h3>
<p>1.1.1.3</p>
<p>1.1.1.4</p>
```

Rendered as:

**From**

1.1.1.1

**To**

1.1.1.2

**Both**

1.1.1.3

1.1.1.4

Comment: This is really close to what I need. From here I can modify & continue working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that copies the document as is and only adds an attribute to the rules in situ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="from" match="from/rule" use="name" />
<xsl:key name="to" match="to/rule" use="name" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rule">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="group">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="parent::from and not(key('to', name))">
                    <xsl:text>from</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="parent::to and not(key('from', name))">
                    <xsl:text>to</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>both</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<acl>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <from>
    <rule group="from">
      <name>1.1.1.1</name>
      <pattern>1.1.1.1</pattern>
      <allow/>
      <log>true</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </rule>
    <rule group="both">
      <name>1.1.1.3</name>
      <pattern>1.1.1.3</pattern>
      <allow/>
      <log>false</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </rule>
    <rule group="both">
      <name>1.1.1.4</name>
      <pattern>1.1.1.4</pattern>
      <deny/>
      <log>true</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </rule>
    <fallthrough>
      <allow/>
      <log>true</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </fallthrough>
  </from>
  <to>
    <rule group="to">
      <name>1.1.1.2</name>
      <pattern>1.1.1.2</pattern>
      <allow/>
      <log>true</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </rule>
    <rule group="both">
      <name>1.1.1.3</name>
      <pattern>1.1.1.3</pattern>
      <allow/>
      <log>false</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </rule>
    <rule group="both">
      <name>1.1.1.4</name>
      <pattern>1.1.1.4</pattern>
      <deny/>
      <log>true</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </rule>
    <fallthrough>
      <allow/>
      <log>false</log>
      <alarm>0</alarm>
    </fallthrough>
  </to>
</acl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I might not be clear enough, but I don't want to add to the XML file. But rather, output to a HTML document that shows those "IP addresses". Such as "1.1.1.1 is from 'from'", "1.1.1.3 is from 'both'", "1.1.1.2 is from 'to'". I tried modifying what you provided, but it still wouldn't test correctly. It ended up showing "both" for all of them.

Comment: @tyler I have added another version with HTML output to my first answer; it's a rather trivial modification.