# Match and display missing node in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have to match one set of nodes to another set of nodes to see which one is missing. And when it is missing, I need to display the name of the missing node. Can only use XSLv1.0.

**XML:**

```
<root>
  <ph>
    <wb>full_list</wb>
      <wbs>
        <categories>
          <rule>
            <name>Intimate Clothing</name>
            <value>95</value>
            <allow/>
            <log>true</log>
          </rule>
          <rule>
            <name>Books</name>
            <value>825</value>
            <allow/>
            <log>true</log>
          </rule>
          <rule>
            <name>Violence</name>
            <value>93</value>
            <allow/>
            <log>true</log>
          </rule>
      </categories>
    </wbs>
  </ph>
          ... hundreds of lines later ...
  <ph>
    <wb>items</wb>
      <wbs>
        <categories>
          <rule>
            <value>93</value>
            <allow/>
            <log>true</log>
          </rule>
          <rule>
            <value>95</value>
            <allow/>
          <log>true</log>
        </rule>
      </categories>
    </wbs>
  </ph>
</root>
```

**Desired Result:**

`Books` <-- because "Books" is the missing one from the two sets of nodes (or value "825").

**The XSL I have:**

```
    <xsl:variable name="ph" select="root/ph"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$ph[wb = 'full_list']/wbs/categories/rule[value != $ph[wb = 'items']/wbs/categories/rule/value]">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But this just ends up displaying every `<name>` on the `full_list`. It should only display "Books". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a class assignment, or do you just need a workable solution? If the latter I'd go looking at [Dave Pawson's XSL FAQ Website](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/) to see if there's a canned solution there. If the former, you might not want to do so since if the professor notices too much similarity he might dock you points for copying rather than developing your own.

Comment: Your XPath is missing the `wb/wbs` but I don't know if adding that is going to get the output you want. Assuming your variable matches `ph`.

Comment: @keshlam This isn't a class assignment. I intern at a networking company and I'm simply stuck trying to fix a bug that reports the settings of a network equipment. I've taken a look at the website, did a bunch of googling and found similar topics, but they were about appending nodes instead of reporting what's missing.

Comment: @matthew-green Just realized the wb/wbs xpath, thanks, I quickly rewrote something of the similar nature and missed the xpath since I'm not suppose to show exact coding (per company policy), now fixed xpath in above XSL.

Comment: You should be using a **key**, in the same way as shown in the answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710665. Note also that your example input lacks a root element. The XSL you show is useless since we can't see how the $ph variable was defined, nor the context in which the for-each instruction is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your method does not work is that you are using `node[child!=node-set]` instead of `node[not(child=node-set)]`. The first construct says "every node that has at least one child that does not match **some** member of node-set"; the second one says "every node that has no child that matches **any** member of node-set".

I repeat my recommendation to use a key, which is more efficient in finding "related" items.

Comment: Got it working with node-set[not(child=node-set)]. Took a bit of tinkering with before I was able to get it working. I tried many variations of it and nothing worked. The key never worked for me in this solution, probably because my understanding of it is still at the minimum. Thank you for the help! Management is pushing for release next week. Great amount of stress is gone since I'm no longer crunching on time and can spend the next day working on other parts of it.

Comment: Also found some useful notes from: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/44071-Comparing-two-sets-of-nodes-and-finding-the-unique-nodes for anyone who is stumbling on this similar type problem in the future.